# How to compute localization of module $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

How to compute localization of module $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(p)$?

For example, let $M = \mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$. Then how to compute $M_{(2)}$?

I'm also wondering if this can be generalized into polynomial case. For example, let $M=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$. Then could we compute $M_{\mathfrak p}$ for prime ideal $\mathfrak p$?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What does the definition of localization force you to invert?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Here is my attempt. $(\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z)_{(2)} = \mathbb Z_{(2)}/12\mathbb Z_{(2)} = \mathbb Z_{(2)}/4\mathbb Z_{(2)}$. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You’re almost done. What are the cosets?

Comment: Oh, It seems to be $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Localizing at $(2)$ means you invert all other primes so the $3$ disappears. Once you get to $\mathbb{Z}/4$ all the other primes are invertible so there's nothing left to invert.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think I actually prove $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z_{(2)} = \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. I'm wondering if there is any generalization of this identity. When will we have $M/nM = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ in general?

Comment: Tensoring by $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ fixes any abelian $p$-group.